# How to preview JSON respond_to format in rails app within iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to view the JSON response for my model object, but I can't get it working.

https://store.myshopify.com/apps/products/293.json
leads to {"errors":"Not Found"}
I'm expecting to see the model data in JSON format. What am I doing wrong?

Products Controller

```
def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # default html response
    format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end
```

console.log returns: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm under the impression that by using format.json { render json: @product }, that rails can just create a JSON object out from the model and I can view it just by going to /product/id.json. Is that not correct?

UPDATE: So, the app renders inside of a shopify iframe. I'm using cloud9 for my IDE, developing a Shopify plugin app. and so it does not render properly due to some CORS issue. I tried adding gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

and in my application.rb

```
# CORS handling
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get]
  end
end
```

but that still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please show your console log. I would like to see in which format you are expecting the response from the server.

Comment: are you sure in database there is a `product` with id `293`?

Comment: Seems like you don't have a record with id `293`

Comment: I do have a record with that id, and the normal /products/293 page works. Once I have /products/293.json nothing shows up